# Why am I getting server errors with Google App Engine's tutorials?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following Web Development (cs253) at **www.udacity.com**, and suddenly started getting errors: this is my very first stint with web development.

After having successfully followed the "hello world" tutorial on Google App Engine's website (as suggested by the video classes on Udacity) I started making small changes, and kept resubmitting the newer modified versions, until after 4 or 5 times I started getting the following error:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

I tried to (1) wait a while and then retry, (2) reload the latest version, (3) reload the immediately previous version known to work, (4) clean up the history of Chrome (I'm running MacOS Lion version 10.7.5) -> Nothing. I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you: *any* help is welcome!

Last thing: I am using Python 2.7 (not sure it matters, but still.)

---

PS: Here is the code:

## helloworld.py

```
import webapp2

form="
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
#       self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
#       self.response.out.write('Hello, Udacity!!')
        self.response.out.write(form)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

## app.yaml

```
application: chris73it-helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

That's it: only 2 files.

Problem solved: the 2 of the 3 double quotes had disappeared while editing the code: now it works. Unfortunately, because this was my very first post on SO, I am not allowed to "give +1 points" :-( Sorry about that!

Comment: Could you pls share your code which you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

After `form=` do you actually only have one `"` or is that just a copy and paste error. Because you should have `"""` to match the closing quotes at line 8.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: the double quotes went missing: it works now!

Comment: Until you get better at scanning a bit of code for syntax errors you can try using tools like pylint, or pyflakes to point you in the right direction. Even just running `python helloworld.py` will tell you that you have a syntax error and vaguely where to find it.

Comment: An automatic pre-screening of the code performed by some tool is going to save me tons of time: thanks a lot for the hint!